# Magento2: How to get list of category's dropdown attributes?

Tags: magento2.3, attributes, custom-attributes, category-attribute

I am using Magento 2.3 and I want to get list of category's dropdown attributes and their values?

For example I have a **Furniture** category and in this category I have **Color** and **Manufacturer** attributes in sidebar navigation, I want to get these two attributes(Color and manufacturer) and their values based on **Furniture** category. You can check my requirement with the help of below image:-
[image]
Please help me how to get this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

Let's say that `$category` is the instance of the current category;

```
$collection = $category->getProductCollection()->addAttributeToSelect(['manufacturer', 'color']);
$manufacturers = [];
$colors = [];
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    $manufacturer = $product->getData('manufacturer');
    if ($manufacturer && !isset($manufacturers[$manufacturer])) {
         $manufacturers[$manufacturer] = $product->getAttributeText('manufacturer');
    }

    $color = $product->getData('color');
    if ($color && !isset($colors[$color])) {
         $colors[$color] = $product->getAttributeText('color');
    }
}
```

after this, `$manufacutrers` and `$colors` should contain all the values you need. The key is the id, and the value is the option label.
But this may cause performance issues if you have a large product collection.

Comment: Thanks @marius to quick answer, but I also want related attributes dynamically, so when category selected, associated attributed listed in next dropdown and their value in next dropdown.